# How To Create Column Filter List and Display Different Text Than Cell Value In Excel

Tags: excel, filter, formatting, columnsorting

At my job, we use a tracking system for docket numbers that are formatted as 2022-xxx-xxxxx (year, 3 digit group identifier, 5 digit task # identifier.

Our company is comprised of around 10 different groups, and each group is assigned a 3 digit group identifier. For example, the group called FM is identified as 507. Another group, NC, is identified as 503. A third group, EM, and is identified as 509.  The group identifier will always be the second number after the first dash in the docket number.

What I would like to do in excel is create a tracking sheet where I can use a column filter to sort all the active dockets by their group identifier. I want the value in the cell to display as the full docket number 2022-507-xxxxx but for the Column filter list option to display only the 3 digit group identifier number.

I’ve attached a mock up image of what I would like it to display as for context (made using photoshop)

Any help is greatly appreciated. [Column Filter vs Cell Value Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d7L5.jpg)

Comment: Use a combination of `MID()` and `UNIQUE()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a new column `=MID(C1,6,3)` and use a filter on that one?